# missing common_matlab.h when compiling a .cpp/mex file

Tags: c++, matlab, mex

I am trying to compile a .cpp file to generate a .mex file through MATLAB, however I get the following error

```
myFileName.cpp:20:27: fatal error: common_matlab.h: No such file or directory
 #include "common_matlab.h"
```

After a search on the web I have not found any info about this header. Is it a standard header file in mex compiling process?

Comment: It looks like you added that include to your code, not MATLAB

Comment: I forgot to mention that obviously the .cpp code is not mine, so, yes, the include is inside the .cpp file, but the header is not provided with the code so I was wondering if it was a standard header file.

Comment: I dont think its a MATLAB header, no

Comment: Matlab will generate its own header file at time of code generation.